# Twitter API user_timeline not retrieving all tweets

Tags: api, twitter, wordpress

For some reason when I go to this link plugging in ABCSMinistries screenname I only get 1 result:
[http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=ABCSMinistries&count=4&exclude_replies=$exclude_replies](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=ABCSMinistries&count=4&exclude_replies=%24exclude_replies)

I've since research and come across this link as well with the same results
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/ABCSMinistries.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4

But when I try any other screenname I get 4 results as expected (unless the user doesn't have four. ABCSMinistries definitely has more than 1 (32 to be exact) so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't seeing the retweets that user has made.  Your call to the API needs to include

```
include_rts=1
```

See the documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: Awesome thanks. Took awhile to test it because the plugin caches results using  `set_transient($transName, $tweets, 60 * $cacheTime);
            update_option($backupName, $tweets);` Can't figure out a way to clear that cache without manually doing it in phpmyadmin

Comment: The included link does not work anymore because Twitter changed the developer portal URL.